# How to make websites use light mode by default in a night mode Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

I am using Safari in dark mode (dark toolbar, etc). Some websites would use `prefers-color-scheme` CSS property to automatically trigger dark schemes. Is there a way to tell all websites to use light scheme by default, even my Safari is in the dark mode?